# Mouse sometimes behaves abnormally in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mouse

I have Windows 7 with a USB optical mouse.

Sometimes my mouse starts behaving abnormally. When I move the cursor everything starts highlighting. Right and left clicking does not work all the time.

I am unable to write properly. Whenever I start writing text it starts highlighting and the cursor moves backwards automatically.

I always have to restart the computer and then it works okay. The problem happens every few months. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using a different mouse to see if you get the same result? It could be drivers, the mouse failing due to wear and tear over time, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a laptop and are you accidentally resting your hand on the trackpad under the keyboard?  Far too often have I accidentally "clicked" the trackpad with the palm of my hand.